# Issues with if iv1 >= hpmin: ; hpmin = iv1

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I apologize for the rather vague title, I couldn't think of a good way to describe this issue.  Basically I have

```
def collectivs():
while True:
    a = input('Input format IVtype X-Y where X is the lowest possible IV and Y is the highest.\nIV types are:[HP, ATK, DEF, SPA, SPD, SPE]\n')
    hpmin = 0
    hpmax = 31
    hp = "%s-%s" % (hpmin, hpmax)
    try: 
        ivtypeup, ivrange = a.split(' '); ivtype = str.lower(ivtypeup)
        print(ivtype, ivrange)
        if ivtype not in('hp''atk''def''spa''spd''spe'):
            print('k')
        else:
            print('k its working')
            nonintivs = ivrange.split('-')
            iv1, iv2 = list(map(int, nonintivs))
            print(type(iv1))
            if ivtype == 'hp':
                if iv1 >= hpmin:
                    hpmin = iv1
                if iv2 < hpmax:
                    hpmax = iv2
                else:
                    print('k')
```

more specifically I'm trying to say "if iv1 is greater than hpmin, change hpmin to iv1." and then repeat this multiple times so I can enter say: 
hp 23-31
hp 22-29
and then the result would be:
hp 23-29 because 29 is less than hp hpmax and 23 is more than the iv1 inputted in the second input. The problem is it's not doing that, in the example above if I input those the final result would be 22-29, even though it should be 23-29.
I can't think of a better way to describe it, but I've been staring at this code for an hour trying to figure out what's wrong with it, and being a beginner I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: The programming language this is in would constitute a good tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the hpmin and hpmax initial assignments outside of the while loop:

```
hpmin = 0
hpmax = 31
```

[Before-and-after diff here](https://www.filediff.net/d/NFWoL65ejM/)